# No gulpfile found error But i installed gulp clearly

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, gulp

I'm trying to install 'gulp' by using npm and then There is an error.

```
C:\Users\SAMSUNG\myapp2>gulp
[13:22:54] No gulpfile found
```

I installed gulp clearly as this statement

```
C:\Users\SAMSUNG\myapp2>npm install global gulp
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
myapp2@1.0.0 C:\Users\SAMSUNG\myapp2
+-- global@4.3.1
`-- gulp@3.9.1
```

I updated graceful-fs version of course. And there is gulp in my diretory
C:\Users\SAMSUNG\myapp2\node_modules.bin. And also run this statement

```
npm install{....}
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Why dose it occurred 'no found gulpflie'???

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says, there is no gulpfile. You need a gulpfile.

Here is an example of one https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js

Comment: Is this link about 'How to install gulpfile'? I'm leaning by laravel book. This book told me that just run "npm install global gulp" and "npm install".

Comment: Just installing Gulp is not enough. Gulp needs a configuration file (known as a gulpfile) in your project.

Comment: So should i create "gulpfile.babel.js" in my project root directory? Just copied that file and pasted that?

Comment: You need to do a Gulp tutorial to learn how it works https://scotch.io/tutorials/automate-your-tasks-easily-with-gulp-js

Comment: Thank you! But what's the meaning of that sentence "npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})"

Comment: It tells you in the message. It's skipping an optional dependency for that package. This is just a warning and is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you very much. finally.....just one more question. laravel doc told me that if i wanted to install Elixir, i need gulp and npm install. that is all you need. But when i use $ gulp, Error was shown me "Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'".  Why is this?

Comment: You need to install laravel-elixir with npm... npm install --save laravel-elixir

Comment: Why should i install "laravel-elixir" and "laravel-elixir-vue" and etc myself? Doc told me that 'pakage.json' in my project may already have that, So i won't have to install that thing my self.....

Comment: You need to learn how npm works. Installing it basically just means adding it to your package.json. If it's already in there, you can install the module with npm install

Comment: Oh...i installed that all. But i get this error "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\myapp2>gulp
C:\Users\SAMSUNG\myapp2\node_modules\laravel-elixir-vue\main.js:4
    Elixir.webpack.mergeConfig({
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'mergeConfig' of undefined". I'm node.js and laravel beginner T.T